# How to integrate GitFlow into existing project?

Tags: git, git-flow

I need to integrate existing project into GitFlow branching model. All guides I've seen so far takes a clear repo as a base. Is it possible to run GitFlow over existing Git repository and preserve current history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. It is only a branching model, it doesn't change the past. I would, if possible, make sure that you source base is stable. It would be great if you did this right after a release, it might make things clearer.

But you can even have some people using git flow and others not. It breaks the branching model's purity, but it doesn't change the git repository.